# Centering google maps on a placeholder

Tags: google-maps

Does anyone know if its possible to center a embedded map on an actual placeholder? I mean so that that when the map loads and is centered you can actually see the landmark and the marker in the the map?

```
    function initialize() {
        var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
    var map_options = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.515727, -0.141388),
      zoom: 16,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options)
    }
```

This is my initialise function that inputs the coordinates of the shop I want to have directions to. However there is not placeholder (pin marker) over the shop. Am I able to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to explicitly specify the marker and set its position. Following your example...

```
var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
 var position = new google.maps.LatLng(51.515727, -0.141388);
 var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 16,
                center: position,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options);
```

You have to then create the marker object...

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: position,
                    map: map,
                    title: "ANYTHING YOU WANT"
                });
```

That's all you need to do really, but notice that you can always change the center of the map at anytime...

```
map.setCenter(position);
```

For more info visit the [Developer's Site API Reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference)

Answer (score 0):

```
function initialize() {
            var map_canvas = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
        var map_options = {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.515727, -0.141388),
          zoom: 16,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options);

         var point = new google.maps.LatLng(51.515727, -0.141388);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position:point,
            map: map,
        });
        }
```